# Expand all non-leading tabs but keep leading tabs

Tags: indentation, tab-characters, alignment

I want to use tabs for indentation and spaces for alignment in the following way:

- keep tab characters (like `noexpandtab`) for all leading tabs of a file, but
- expand tabs (like `expandtab`) that occur *after a non-tab character* within a line, such that
- such tabs are expanded as spaces to the next tabstop and preferably
- shift+backspace deletes spaces back to the previous tabstop.

so in short, I want Vim to behave as with `noexpandtab`, but all inline tabs are automatically converted to spaces.

Can I set up Vim/Neovim to do this?

So for instance, marking tabs as `›–––` and spaces as `·`, take a buffer with `ts=4` like this.

```
  1   5   9
1 abc·def·ghi
2 ›---·
3 ›---
4 ›–––foo
```

hitting tab in insert mode at the end of line will:

- in line 2 insert three spaces
- in line 3 insert a tab character
- in line 4 insert a single space

hitting shift + backspace in insert mode in  line 1 will:

- at `c` delete `ab`
- at `d` delete `abc·`
- at `h` delete `g`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tabs for indentation, spaces for alignment](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/4572/tabs-for-indentation-spaces-for-alignment)

Comment: The infamous "indent with tabs, align with spaces" holy grail… still can't be done without some serious trickery: https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/4572/tabs-for-indentation-spaces-for-alignment.

Comment: @VivianDeSmedt you keep editing my question, capitalising a couple of words? is that really necessary? my writing style is lower case words only and i like to stay consistent with this. in my view, making all questions on vi.stackexchange consistent in style seems like a hopeless endeavour anyhow. so as i see no other purpose than that in capitilising letters, is it alright with you if we could just leave the questions as i style it?

Comment: @romainl no, it does not answer my question. please note that i ask something different, namely for a configuration which merely helps me do the alignments manually in a sensible way, not for a configuration to do the alignment automatically. (my hope is to have indentation with tabs automated and alignment facilitated: vim/neovim does not need to know how i want my stuff aligned.)

Comment: I'm afraid what you want doesn't exist, at least as a combination of options.

Comment: @romainl hm. that’s actually really sad.

Comment: Less sad than the realisation that there are people out there who still want that kind of thing :-).

Comment: @romainl how so? in any case, i was too quick dismiss the answer that you have linked – i had a second look and i misunderstood what the `vim-stabs` plugin is about – it actually solves most of my question. sorry for the misunderstanding.