# change behaviour of > / < and >> / << to insert / remove only leading tabs

Tags: key-bindings, neovim, indentation, tab-characters, alignment

i want `>` / `<` and `>>` / `<<` to simply insert and remove tab characters *at the beginning of the line*.

> *variant*: i would even prefer to have`>` / `<`  and `>>`/ `<<` insert / remove a tab character *at the position of the last tab character of each line within the selection* (defaulting to the first character of each line within the selection whenever none such tab character is found).

can i change their behaviour to do so?

**example**. denoting tabs as `›–––` and spaces as `·`, say i have some text like the following.

```
›–––··A
›–––······B
›–––····C
```

i have `preserveindent` set. selecting all three lines in visual mode and pressing `>` thus far yields the following.

```
›–––··›–··A
›–––······›–··B
›–––····›–––C
```

clearly i want it to be as follows.

```
›–––›–––··A
›–––›–––······B
›–––›–––····C
```

*variant*. the variant allows to indent in a more reasonable way some text with a preceding comment `# …` like the following.

```
›–––··A
›–––······B
#›––····C
```

indenting the three lines by pressing `>` is then supposed to yield the following.

```
›–––›–––··A
›–––›–––······B
#›––›–––····C
```

**context**. it appears that vim/neovim does something way more complicated, namely to compute the indentation level of each line by counting its leading tabs and spaces, then increase / decrease this indentation level and finally indent the entire line fully anew by inserting a number of first tabs, then spaces corresponding to the freshly increased / decreased indentation level.

so this messes up the indentation structure when using “tabs for indentation, spaces for alignment”.

if `preserveindent` is on, it seems that indentation is increased / decreased by inserting a mixture of first spaces, then tabs right before the first non-white-space character, which is again way more complicated than what i want.

i want this for a sane configuration for using tabs as indentation, spaces as alignment; this is a follow-up to a [previous question about leading tabs](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/41751/expand-all-non-leading-tabs-but-keep-leading-tabs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the code that does the job (only `>` and `<`, but you can easily add `>>` or `<<`).
Assuming you have `preserveindent` set, it works in visual mode, as well as range motions e.g. `>2j` or `<}`.

```
function! DoIndent(type, ...)
  if a:0
    " visual mode
    exec "sil! keepp '<,'>s/^/" . repeat("\t", v:count1) . "/"
  else
    " normal mode (followed by a motion)
    exec "sil! keepp '[,']s/^/\t/"
  endif
endfunction
function! DoDedent(type, ...)
  if a:0
    " visual mode
    exec "sil! keepp '<,'>s/^\t\\{," . v:count1 . "}//"
  else
    " normal mode (followed by a motion)
    exec "sil! keepp '[,']s/^\t//"
  endif
endfunction

nnoremap <silent> > :set opfunc=DoIndent<CR>g@
vnoremap <silent> > :<C-U>call DoIndent(visualmode(), 1)<CR>
nnoremap <silent> < :set opfunc=DoDedent<CR>g@
vnoremap <silent> < :<C-U>call DoDedent(visualmode(), 1)<CR>
```

The basic idea is: to insert a leading `\t`, replace start-of-line i.e. `^` with a `\t`; to remove one, replace `^\t` with nothing. So we map `>` and `<` to perform such substitutions.

Since substitution is not affected by `preserveindent`, we end just just inserting/deleting one tab, without any extra spaces.

For example, the `"sil! keepp '<,'>s/^/\t/"` breaks down to

1. `sil!` supress messages from `:s`
2. `keepp` keep the search pattern (`@/`) unchanged because normally `:s` clobbers it
3. `'<,'>` let the substitution work on visually selected lines. Similarly, `'[,']` means the lines covered by a motion like `2j` or `}`.
4. `s/^/\t/` substitute start-of-line with a tab, essentially adding a leading tab

**update:** Use `repeat` and the `\{` regex to perform multiple shifts in visual mode e.g. in visual mode, `2<` dedents each line of the selection by up to two `\t`'s.

Comment: FWIW, `:substitute` accepts `\t` in both the pattern and replacement to stand for a Tab character. `:execute` is not needed here… just write `:silent! keeppatterns '[,']substitute/^\t/`, for example.

Comment: nice! can i extend this to use the current `v:count` somehow?

Comment: in the meantime i’ve been dabbling at creating a `>>` solution incorporating `v:count`, but it looks very contrived:

`nnoremap <expr> >> '^' . ('T<tab>' ? 'T<tab>' : '0') . ( v:count == 0 ? '' : v:count ) . 'i<c-v><tab><esc>'`

and

 `nnoremap <expr> << '^T<tab>d' . ( v:count > 0 ? v:count . 'F<tab>' : 'F<tab>' )`

and unindenting doesn’t work if the given `v:count` is greater than the number of leading tabs (the desired behaviour to unindent as many tabs as possible).

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Thank you! I always used a manual ^I but `\t` is definitely more portable.

Comment: @windfish I guess you would like `v:count` to designate the number of `\t` inserted/deleted, but vim **only does it  for visual selections** instead of `>>` or `>{motion}`. For example `3>2j` is essentially equal to `>6j`, and `6>>` essentially shifts six lines by one shiftwidth instead of one line by six shiftwidths. So I'm trying to keep a consistent behavior, but surely I modified the post to use `v:count` for visual selections.

Comment: @Hoblovski indeed – i didn’t realise that vim doesn’t do multiple indents on movements. in any case, thank you very much!

Comment: @windfish for multiple indents, use `:[range]>[>>>…]`, but it won't use the custom code. Or use your `>` with `.`, though it's possible using tpope/vim-repeat and `call repeat#set` is necessary to make that work as desired.